# NodeJs best practices for scheduled process?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm currently working on a large scale Tiktok like app where a video will be exist for 5 days. My question how should I schedule to take down the video after 5 days? 2 Method that I came up are either I can build a background service worker that will continuously loop through the database and check if the video should be down or not OR I can put it in a setTimeOut() for 5 days, which means its gonna be on the RAM and there need to be a service that restart all the setTimeOut() in case the server is down. I'm using AWS EC2 so I wonder which method will be scalable and save some money. Thank you.

Comment: Or you schedule a job via the operating system's job scheduler that executes at least once a day to remove stuff. Mysql also has a built-in scheduler, but I would probably still use an external one, since node.js has lot more flexibility and features than mysql's sql language..

Comment: I wouldn't use the setTimeout method - what if the server goes down ... better to check every now and then (maybe triggered by accesses to your system, i.e. someone accesses any page or whatever, and a "cleanup" is triggered by the access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use queue management for storing tasks on it.

suppose you have a queue that holds your tasks inside it. you have a consumer that listens to your queue. if a message sends, the consumer reads the message and handles the job for you.

but there is a challenge. **when** you should send your task into the queue and **when** the consumer should handle the task. for the availability part,  message brokers are the good choices but managing the process is up to your approach, if you have a microservice system design, you can write your consumer as a service.

[rabbit-MQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)  and [kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) are the most popular message brokers.

of course, you should know about **task queue** and **message queues** concepts.

take a look at the difference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/669434/whats-the-difference-between-a-task-queue-and-a-message-queue-in-rabbitmq

https://www.tech101.in/message-queue-and-task-queue/

there is a simple task queue package that works with Redis :

[bee-queue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue)

> note that, handling the message brokers are complicated in the
> **production** level.

and you should know about cron systems too:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/automate-linux-tasks-cron